# How many nodes does the code use?

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, nodes

I'm running a Matlab code on a cluster. It is slow and I guess I'm running the code only on one node. How can I check if I'm correct or not? And how can I use all accessible nodes?

Comment: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-to-use-parallel-processing.html

Comment: Thank you, but I need a simple answer. @LeanderMoesinger